# Hide and show menu with the same button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found a tutorial on some dropdown menu using jquery. It works fine but I want to adjust it just a little. Instead of hiding the menu using hovering, I want to have the same button that showed the menu, to hide it when it is being pressed again. So the same button has to both hide and show the dropdown menu.
The script that im using:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled - Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav

        $("ul.topnav li span").click(function () { //When trigger is clicked...

            //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

            $(this).parent().hover(function () {
            }, function () {
                $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
            });

            //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function () {    //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.toggle()` http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$("#yourbutton").click(function() {
    $("#yourmenu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: ha, beat me to it. same fake ID and everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself from adding a CSS rule by using jQuery's `.toggle` method.

```
$('#yourMenu').toggle()
```

This will hide it if it's visible, and show it if it's hidden. You can add a number or `'fast', 'slow'` as a parameter to make it animate.

Answer (score 1):

[**jQuery.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function will do this work for you:

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
    $("#menu").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, toggleClass can be used. Or you can also define your own toggle function in javascript.
you can toggle between the classes or do any other function you want to.

`function tog(elemen){
    if(elemen.className == "show") {
        hide drpdwn 
        elemen.className="hide";
    } else {
        make dropdwn visible
        elemen.className="show";
    }
}`